# Json property structure dependant of another property

Tags: jsonschema

I've been working on a json schema to validate the answers from one of my webservices.

The answer is splitted in two properties: `data` and `status`. If `status.code` is set to 0, then `data` will have to respect a specific schema. Else, if `status.code` is set to -1, `data` won't be read, so I don't want to check if it respects the schema.

Here is the schema :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "id": "file://registration.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "status": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/classes/status"
        }
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/conditions/status-is-ok"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/conditions/status-is-nok"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "classes": {
            "status": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "code": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "code",
                    "message"
                ]
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "propertyA": {
                        "type": "#/definitions/classes/metadatauser"
                    },
                    "propertyB": {
                        "type": "#/definitions/classes/membreinfo"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["propertyA", "propertyB"]
            }
        },
        "conditions": {
            "status-is-ok": {
                "status": {
                    "properties": {
                        "code": 0
                    }
                },
                "data": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/classes/data"
                }
            },
            "status-is-nok": {
                "status": {
                    "properties": {
                        "code": -1
                    }
                },
                "data": {
                    "type": "object"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example of what should not be validated:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "OK"
    }
}
```

At the moment, this portion of code passes, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong here, so I'll try to explain all of them. You were on the right track!

```
"properties": {
    "code": 0
}
```

> The value of "properties" MUST be an object. Each value of this object
> MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.4

You can't put the value you expect as the value for a property key.
You CAN however use the `[const]`[1](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.3) keyword to achive a specific value validation.

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/conditions/status-is-ok"
...
"conditions": {
  "status-is-ok": {
    "status": {
      "properties": {
```

> [The `definitions`] keyword's value MUST be an object.  Each member value of this
> object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-9

This means that you need to treat each value of each key in a defintions as a JSON Schema. If you had a JSON Schema where you did not nest "status" inside a `properties` object, no validation would take place. The same is true for "data".

(Strictly, according to the definitions section of the spec, you MUST NOT nest schemas deeply in the definitions object, but this seems to be supported by some implementations anyway, and resolves using the correct resolution rules. Prefixing may be better.)

The complete fixed schema is as follows.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "id": "file://registration.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/classes/status"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/conditions/status-is-ok"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/conditions/status-is-nok"
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "classes": {
      "status": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "code",
          "message"
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        },
        "required": [
          "propertyA",
          "propertyB"
        ]
      }
    },
    "conditions": {
      "status-is-ok": {
        "properties": {
          "status": {
            "properties": {
              "code": {
                "const": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/classes/data"
          },
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "status-is-nok": {
        "properties": {
          "status": {
            "properties": {
              "code": {
                "const": -1
              }
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "object"
          },
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please do let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.
Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack server should you want to discuss any aspects further! Happy to also comment here.

Comment: Oh, OK, I understand what I missed about the properties value. I also had not seen the "additionalProperties" key anywhere until now, it'll be very useful!

Comment: You're welcome! You may also upvote answers if you accept them.